# Sum of all possible products when each product is truncated if too large

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of sets of real numbers greater than $1$. Each set can have a different quantity of numbers.

> Set $A_1 = \{a_{11}, a_{12},\ldots,a_{1m_1}\}$
>
> Set $A_2 = \{a_{21}, a_{22}, \ldots, a_{2m_2}\}$
>
> $\ldots$
>
> Set $A_N = \{a_{N1}, a_{N2}, \ldots, a_{Nm_N}\}$

If I want the sum of all possible products that have one element from each set, that's easy:

$$\left(a_{11}+a_{12}+\cdots+a_{1m_1}\right)\times \left(a_{21}+a_{22}+\cdots +a_{2m_2}\right)\times\cdots \times\left(a_{N1}+a_{N2}+\cdots+a_{Nm_N}\right).$$

But what i interested in is the sum of all possible products that have one element from each set BUT if the product is Higher than K, then the product must be included as $K$, not as its real value.
Short example:

> Set $A_1 = (2,3)$
>
> Set $A_2 = (7,9)$

$K = 20$,
Usual sum $=14 + 21 + 18 + 27$,
Sum I am interested in: $14 + 20 + 18 + 20$

What's the fastest way to calculate it? is it possible to do this with a neat formula or am I forced to cycle over all combinations?
Thankx

Wentu

Comment: I don't see any way to do this other than checking each one. (unless $K$ is so large that it doesn't impose any constraint, or so small that all the possible sums are bigger than it, or something similarly trivial)